# Error creating bean with name 'hypermediaRepresentionModelProcessorConfigurator'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to run a project on a Spring Boot. I configured the database connection, but there is an error which I cannot understand:

> Error creating bean with name
>   'hypermediaRepresentionModelProcessorConfigurator

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)
2020-03-09 18:19:25.128  INFO 11236 --- [           main] ua.com.snicksmoda.SnicksmodaApplication  : Starting SnicksmodaApplication on SnicksPC with PID 11236 (C:\Users\Snicks\Desktop\snicksmoda\target\classes started by Snicks in C:\Users\Snicks\Desktop\snicksmoda)
2020-03-09 18:19:25.136  INFO 11236 --- [           main] ua.com.snicksmoda.SnicksmodaApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-09 18:19:26.646  INFO 11236 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-09 18:19:26.769  INFO 11236 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 111ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-09 18:19:27.662  INFO 11236 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$548ad0aa] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-09 18:19:27.719  INFO 11236 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-03-09 18:19:27.742  WARN 11236 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hypermediaRepresentionModelProcessorConfigurator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcHateoasConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Users\Snicks\Desktop\snicksmoda\target\classes\ua\com\snicksmoda\configuration\AppConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'dataSource.driverClassName' in value "${dataSource.driverClassName}"
2020-03-09 18:19:27.754  INFO 11236 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-09 18:19:27.766 ERROR 11236 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hypermediaRepresentionModelProcessorConfigurator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcHateoasConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Users\Snicks\Desktop\snicksmoda\target\classes\ua\com\snicksmoda\configuration\AppConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'dataSource.driverClassName' in value "${dataSource.driverClassName}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:722) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at ua.com.snicksmoda.SnicksmodaApplication.main(SnicksmodaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Users\Snicks\Desktop\snicksmoda\target\classes\ua\com\snicksmoda\configuration\AppConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'dataSource.driverClassName' in value "${dataSource.driverClassName}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfiguration' defined in file
```

help solve this problem, maybe someone has met this already!

application properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/snicksmoda
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

server.port=8080

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.debug=true
```

pom (sql):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and class JpaConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfiguration implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Value("${datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${jpa.database-platform}")
    private String databasePlatform;
    @Value("${hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String ddlAuto;

    @Bean
    public DataSource configureDataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(driver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.snicksmoda");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, databasePlatform);
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, ddlAuto);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your JPAConfiguration you use `${datasource.driver-class-name}` and the program is looking for `${dataSource.driverClassName}`. Do you think this could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Following the stack trace provided, there is an error in your app configuration file.

It has to do with this bean: `jpaConfiguration`

Caused by a failure with the injection dependency named:
`'dataSource.driverClassName'` in value `"${dataSource.driverClassName}"`

Here's the issue...in your application properties, the name of the variable does not match the jpaconfiguration. Here's how it should be:

```
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
```

After fixing that, you get the same problem with

```
@Value("${jpa.database-platform}")
private String databasePlatform;
@Value("${hibernate.ddl-auto}")
private String ddlAuto;
```

Just match those names up and I think it should work!

Comment: nothing helps! I've already reviewed everything 100 times in the class, and in the pom, and in properties. tell me where to look, maybe I'm not digging there at all!